# Maximizing the volume of a cuboid

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

> We are looking for the maximum volume of an axis-parallel cuboid that can be inscribed into a given paralleloid. We're looking to maximize $$V:\mathbb{R_+^3\rightarrow R}, V(x,y,z)=2x2y2z, \text{under the constraint that,}\ g(x,y,z)=\bigg(\frac{x}{a}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{y}{b}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{z}{c}\bigg)^2-1=0$$

I'm somewhat familiar with the lagrange multiplier used for maximization problems but I could't manage much in this problem. Utilizing the lagrange multiplier, we wish to solve the system of $$\nabla f(x,y,z)=\lambda\nabla g(x,y,z) \\ \implies 8yz=2\lambda\frac{x}{a^2} ,\ 8xz=2\lambda \frac{y}{b^2},\ 8xy=2\lambda\frac{z}{c^2} $$
I know the expression can be simplified via algebra but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: This is not a paraboloid, it is an ellipsoid.

Comment: Supposing that $x,y,z\neq 0$, from your first and second equations you get $\frac{y}{x}=\frac{x}{y}\frac{b^2}{a^2}\,\Rightarrow\frac{x^2}{a^2}=\frac{y^2}{b^2}$, etc. Then use the constrain $g(x,y,z)$ to find $x,y,z$, and prove that this is a local maximum of $V(x,y,z)$.